# How do I stop seconds displaying 60 before going back to 0

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to display the time in the player's UI but I can't seem to stop the seconds displaying 60 before it goes back to 0. I thought it would do everything in the if statement first before displaying anything, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Here is my code:

```
private void Update() {

    seconds += timeMultiplier * Time.deltaTime;

    if (seconds >= 60) {
        seconds -= 60;
        minutes += 1;
    } else if (minutes >= 60) {
        minutes -= 60;
        hours += 1;
    } else if (hours >= 24) {
        hours -= 24;
        days += 1;
    } else if (days >= 7) {
        days -= 7;
        weeks += 1;
    } else if (weeks >= 52.17857f) {
        weeks -= 52.17857f;
        years += 1;
    }

}

public string DisplayTimeInformation() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    builder.Append(hours.ToString("#00")).Append(":").Append(minutes.ToString("#00"));

    if (displaySeconds) {
        builder.Append(":").Append(seconds.ToString("#00")).Append(" ");
    } else {
        builder.Append(" ");
    }

    return builder.ToString();
}
```

I tried using a second `displayedSeconds` that is the same as the normal `seconds` variable and clamping it to 59, and even though it was technically still accurate, it would linger on 59 for a bit and then speed up from 00 to 01 before returning to normal which just doesn't look nice.

Comment: Why even try to calculate all this? Just record the time something started (`var startedOn = DateTime.Now;`) and then every time you display the duration do `var difference = DateTime.Now - startedOn;` which gives you a nice `TimeSpan` object that you can display easily.

Comment: The two methods you have shown are almost certainly running on separate threads. You probably need to synchronize them somehow if you *must* do it this way instead of how @DavidG suggested (or something similar).

Comment: The two method posted have to be synchronized so you don't display until the time get set back to zero.

Comment: Together with what the others said - if you still want to use your own calculation there are some other issues. The if-else if - - logic will e.g. also show 60 minutes as you do not update the minutes if you updated the seconds in the same cycle.

Comment: Incidentally, that code for the years isn't going to work so well in leap years...

Comment: Sorry everyone yeah this might not be the best implementation it was just what I ended up coming up with (still pretty new to unity), but it's just meant to be for an in-game time system rather than something connected to real-life time. Also, didn't know anything about synchronizing methods until now so I'll have to look into that, thanks.

Comment: Also yeah there are a lot of problems with that code (no leap years, the weeks to years check wouldn't work properly) as I ended up just getting stuck on my original problem and didn't notice those things until now, but what @SviatoslavVovdenko suggested is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is more easy to use TimeSpan for calculations. You can use this class for obtaining hours, minutes and seconds depens on deltaTime and timeMultiplier:

```
 public class Timer
    {
        public int Seconds => timeSpan.Seconds;

        public int Minutes => timeSpan.Minutes;

        public int Hours => timeSpan.Hours;

        private TimeSpan timeSpan;

        public void Update(double timeMultiplier, double deltaTime)
        {
            timeSpan = timeSpan.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeMultiplier * deltaTime));

            Console.WriteLine(timeSpan.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss"));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to calculate all of those time properties. It's much easier to record the time something started:

```
var startedOn = DateTime.Now;
```

and then every time you display the duration do:

```
var difference = DateTime.Now - startedOn;
```

Which gives you a nice `TimeSpan` object that you can display easily:

```
var timeInString = difference.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
```

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings) for how you can specify your own format string.

Comment: I'm still quite new so sorry if I'm doing anything unnecessary. I had a look at the link you posted and the method you suggested seems like a good idea but I'm trying to set up an in-game time system, rather than one that's concurrent with the pc's system time. The first `seconds += timeMultiplier * Time.deltaTime;` line let's me change `timeMultiplier` to, say, 4, so that even though the scale(?) is correct, time just passes by 4 times as fast so players don't actually have to wait a full day for it to turn to night time for an event or something like that.